# Generated Eclipse JAXB classes / no namespace

Tags: eclipse, namespaces, jaxb

I use Eclipse (right-click -> JAXB Classes) to generate JAXB classes out of an existing XSD.

The XSD has a namespace definition.

Unfortunately in the generated classes the namespace definitions are missing.

What I get: 
@XmlElement(required = true)

What I *should* get:
@XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "http://rest.mycompany.com/schema/product/1.0")

When I generate the classes with xjc it works (namespaces are added).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a package-info.java generated that contains the namespace information?:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html